# Learnyounode tutorial#11 HTTP File Server

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following is my code

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var arguments = process.argv;
var path = process.argv[3];
var path2 = arguments[3];

var server = http.createServer(
    function (req, res)
    {

    console.log('path1'+path);
    console.log('path2'+path2);
    console.log('path3'+arguments[3]);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(arguments[3]);
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    }
);

server.listen(arguments[2]);
```

if i pass path or path2 to fs.createReadStream(), my code works, but if i pass arguments[3], it fails, console.log(path3) also prints undefined. I don't understand this. Someone please explain. Thanks.

Comment: `path2` prints the correct output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulation you just discovered the arguments `attribute` of the `function object` of the JS please refer [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to know more about it

> The **arguments** object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

try `console.log(arguments)` or

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var parguments = process.argv;
var path = process.argv[3];
var path2 = parguments[3];

var server = http.createServer(
    function (req, res)
    {

    console.log('path1'+path);
    console.log('path2'+path2);
    console.log('path3'+parguments[3]);
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(parguments[3]);
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    }
);

server.listen(parguments[2]);
```

notice I've changed the name of the `arguments` to `parguments`

Comment: Hi, it's you again, appreciate your help! Apparently there's still much for me to learn in the JS basic.

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) { 

res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' })

fs.createReadStream(process.argv[3]).pipe(res);
});

server.listen(Number(process.argv[2]));
```